# How to edit a webpage's pseudo classes using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a Chrome extension that "unblurs" a series of images on a webpage. I'm very new to all this and I just wanted to know if I was on the right track.

From what I've seen, each image is contained in a  tag that looks like this:

```css
<div class="Bdrs(8px) Bgz(cv) Bgp(c) Ov(h) StretchedBox Ir(p) Cnt($blank)::a StretchedBox::a Bg($inherit)::a Scale(1.3)::a Scale(1.2)::a--s Blur(12px)::a">
```

In order for the picture to be unblurred, the Blur(12px) pseudo class must be changed to Blur(0px). I'm not getting any results from what I've tried, but I feel as though my logic is right. All I want the extension to do is automate the process of using "Inspect Element" to edit the page.

```js
var profilePic = document.getElementsByClassName("Bdrs(8px) Bgz(cv) Bgp(c) Ov(h) StretchedBox Ir(p) Cnt($blank)::a StretchedBox::a Bg($inherit)::a Scale(1.3)::a Scale(1.2)::a--s Blur(12px)::a");
    for(var i = 0; i < profilePic.length(); i++) {
        profilePic[i].classList.remove("Bdrs(8px) Bgz(cv) Bgp(c) Ov(h) StretchedBox Ir(p) Cnt($blank)::a StretchedBox::a Bg($inherit)::a Scale(1.3)::a Scale(1.2)::a--s Blur(12px)::a");
        profilePic[i].classList.add("Bdrs(8px) Bgz(cv) Bgp(c) Ov(h) StretchedBox Ir(p) Cnt($blank)::a StretchedBox::a Bg($inherit)::a Scale(1.0)::a Scale(1.0)::a--s Blur(0px)::a");
    }
```

The images on the page should be unblurred, but nothing happens. I may not have my extension set up properly since I've just started looking into this stuff, but I was hoping that someone else with more experience could tell me if my code was okay.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[...document.getElementsByClassName('Blur(12px)::a')]
.forEach(e => e.classList.replace('Blur(12px)::a', 'Blur(0px)::a'));
```

The problem with your current approach is that both `classList.remove(..)` and `classList.add(..)` expect a single parameter, a string representing a single class name or multiple string parameters representing single class names.